# termcal: superscript st, nd, th

Tags: superscripts, termcal

I'd like st, nd, and th of the dates to be superscript like this:

22<sup>nd</sup>

How do I do it?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\newcommand{\WFClass}{%
\skipday % Monday (no class)
\skipday % Tuesday (no class)
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday} % Wednesday
\skipday % Thursday (no class)
\calday[Friday]{\classday} % Friday 
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{%
\options{#1}{\noclassday}
\caltext{#1}{#2}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{1/20/2020}{16} % Date Classes Begin & Length in Weeks
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\WFClass
% schedule
%\caltexton{1}{1.1, 1.2 Review}
\caltextnext{1.3, 1.4 Review}
\caltextnext{2.1, 2.2 Linear Equations}
% ... and so on

% Holidays
\Holiday{1/20/2020}{Martin Luther King Day}
\Holiday{3/8/2020}{Spring Break}
% ... and so on

\options{4/26/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/27/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/28/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/29/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/30/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\caltext{4/27/2020}{\textbf{Final Exam}}
\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\textsuperscript` (but you shouldn't; the superscripts are relics of the Victorian age, that a well-known word processor arbitrarily inflicted to all users thereof).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{termcal}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@rdend[1]{\textsuperscript{\ifcase#1 th\or st\or nd\or rd\else th\fi}}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\WFClass}{%
\skipday % Monday (no class)
\skipday % Tuesday (no class)
\calday[Wednesday]{\classday} % Wednesday
\skipday % Thursday (no class)
\calday[Friday]{\classday} % Friday 
\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}

\newcommand{\Holiday}[2]{%
\options{#1}{\noclassday}
\caltext{#1}{#2}
}


\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{1/20/2020}{16} % Date Classes Begin & Length in Weeks
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\WFClass
% schedule
%\caltexton{1}{1.1, 1.2 Review}
\caltextnext{1.3, 1.4 Review}
\caltextnext{2.1, 2.2 Linear Equations}
% ... and so on

% Holidays
\Holiday{1/20/2020}{Martin Luther King Day}
\Holiday{3/8/2020}{Spring Break}
% ... and so on

\options{4/26/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/27/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/28/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/29/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\options{4/30/2020}{\noclassday} % finals week
\caltext{4/27/2020}{\textbf{Final Exam}}
\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm not sure why the left column produces overfull boxes.

Comment: the overfull boxes are because of unprotected end lines. I've already fixed it.
I tried this solution in the .sty file but it didn't work. Do you know why?

Comment: Actually, @egreg's solution doesn't work for all dates.

Comment: Looks like the guilty lines in `termcal.sty` are 88, 89, 136, and 141...

Comment: Not sure what to do with these lines. Could you explain? @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: @idonthaveagoat These seem to be the ones responsible for the Overfull boxes. Adding a `%` at their end fix _that_ problem (which you say you already fixed, so not useful to you, sorry).

Comment: To superscript all dates just add this to @egreg's solution:

`\makeatletter \renewcommand\@rd[1]{\ifx#1x\if\last@@1\textsuperscript{th}\else\@rdend{\last@}\fi\else \let\last@@=\last@\def\last@{#1}#1\expandafter\@rd\fi} \makeatother`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik yes, you're right about which lines need a `%`!

Comment: Sure! Get rid of what is aesthetically pleasing, tried by tradition and beautiful and replace it with lazy, ugly, drab and soulless .

Comment: @thebodzio I fully agree: the superscript suffixes are lazy, ugly, drab and soulless.

Comment: @egreg: Yeeeeeah… riiiiiight… 